# Laravel-4 Polymorphic Relationship showing both type with the respective tables

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

i understand how the polymorphic relations works, but still i don't understood how can i get the results of table morphed associating to the respective tables. Let's go with a example for understand better.

we have the normal example with History, Order, and User table.

**History | table**

```
id
historable_id
historable_type
event
```

**Orders | table**

```
id
order
```

**Users | Table**

```
id
fullname
```

Then let's go with the our polymorphic relationship:

**History model**

```
Class History extends Eloquent {
 function historable() {
   $this->morphTo();
 }

}
```

**User model**

```
Class User extends Eloquent {
   function history() {
     $this->morphMany('History','historable');
   }
}
```

**Order model**

```
Class Order extends ELoquent {
  function hisotry() {
    $this->morphMany('History','historable');
  }
}
```

Now if i want get all the users history i can just do something like that

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach ($user->historable as $history) {
  echo "Name:".$user->fullname;
  echo "Event:".$history->event;
}
```

My question is, how can get both of the history of users and orders in one selection and automatically it associates with the datas belonging?

Example of my expectation of the result:

```
<h2>History</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>Category</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Event</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Order</td>
   <td>SmartPhone</td>
   <td>Bought</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>User</td>
   <td>Jhon Smith</td>
   <td>Book SmartPhone</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `History` class as a normal eloquent model. The `historable` relation on the `History` model will return either a `User` or `Order` instance.

And for your expected result, code may be like:

```php
$histories = History::all();

foreach ($histories as $history) {
  echo 'ID:' . $history->id;
  echo 'Category:' . ($history->historable instanceof User) ? 'User' : 'Order';
  echo 'Name:' .  ($history->historable instanceof User) ? $history->historable->fullname  : $history->historable->order ;
  echo "Event:".$history->event;
}
```